# How to take notifications when using Strategy tester of MQL4

Tags: mql4

Is there a way to take logs and Alerts when using Strategy tester of MQL4? They are not working as normal mode when using Strategy tester.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to world of MQL4!

No, Alerts and Notifications are disabled in tester and optimization mode. All you can do is to receive logs that ea made an alert, so watch the logs. If you want to catch some situation (in other words, stop testing once alert is received) - You can use `ExpertRemove()` to stop testing when such situation happens (of course do not forget to remove that alert in the production version)